# VBA copy paste formmating and formulae

Tags: excel, formatting, copy-paste, formulas, vba

I am quite new to VBA, the code below is what I have managed so far but I would like to ask if someone can help with formatting and formulae copying please?

I have the below code running in my project that transfers data from a worksheet called "Update Quality Check Data" to other worksheets based on user names by 1 of 2 ways, either:

- By seeing the user name of the worksheet already exists and just
  copying the relevant data; or,
- By creating a new worksheet with the
  user name as the ws name and copying the data from the data sheet

What I would like to add would be when a new user sheet is created the format and forumlas from the first usersheet are copied into the new sheets and each additional user sheet that is created.

I have seen many threads to copy paste and the arguments between clipboard and pastespecial but now I am rather confused and not sure how to do this for sheets that do not currently exist. Could some please help me?

```
Public Sub transfer() 


Dim ws As Worksheet, wsName As Worksheet 
Dim lRow As Long, lPaste As Long 
Dim sName As String 


Set ws = Worksheets("Update Quality Check Data") 


With ws 
    For lRow = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
        sName = .Cells(lRow, 2) 
        On Error Goto NoSheettFound 
Jumper: 
        Set wsName = Worksheets(sName) 
        On Error Goto 0 
        lPaste = wsName.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Copy Destination:=wsName.Cells(lPaste, 3) 
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Copy Destination:=wsName.Cells(lPaste, 4) 
    Next lRow 
End With 


Exit Sub 


NoSheettFound: 
Set wsName =    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)) 
wsName.Name = sName 
ws.Select 
Goto Jumper 
End Sub
```

Kind Regards

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this two ways.  One, create a template that's a hidden tab that I copy my format from.

Or two, you can bury EACH cell's format in your code and call it for each range you want.  Example:

```
Sub format1(r As Range)

    With r
        .Interior
        .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
        .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .Interior.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0

        .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .Font.TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Italic = True

        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 0
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).TintAndShade = 0
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 0
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).TintAndShade = 0
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Kerry that looks great. Sorry to sound ignorant but can you guide as to how to do this? Lets say for example my template worksheet is called "Bob" and the for matting and formulae are in range D5:G10.

Comment: @JohnWilliams, you could do it like this:  `Sub TestBob()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Bob")
    
    Call format1(ws.Range("D5:G10"))
    
End Sub`   ... this is of course assuming you have the same cells formatted like you want in your template.

Comment: @JohnWilliams, if I was helpful, don't forget to upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

here's one using a template:

```
Sub FormatNewSheet(ws As Worksheet)

Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet
Set wsTemplate = Worksheets("Bob")

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Copy the range from the template
wsTemplate.Range("D5:G10").Copy


'Paste the format to the new range
ws.Select
ws.Range("D5:G10").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Here is a simple test for it, passing the worksheet name to the format sub:

```
Sub TestFormat()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("my new sheet")

Call FormatNewSheet(ws)

End Sub
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Kerry that is ideal appreicate your help

Comment: If it helps you, please don't forget to upvote the solution.   Thank you!